# App crashes when i stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this is the error given in the console. I'm taking a search term and replacing the " " with "+" so it goes into a URL ok, it then fetches RSS feeds based on that search term, this works fine but when i press the refresh button on the toolbar, it crashes with this error:

```
 -[UITableViewCellLayoutManagerSubtitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b67be0

2010-11-14 19:58:01.325 Example[63210:1903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellLayoutManagerSubtitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b67be0'
```

This is actually my code: `terms = [terms stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];`

Comment: `terms` must not be an `NSString`. Can you provide more code?

Comment: Its definitely an NSString: @interface BlogRssParser : NSObject {
 BlogRss * _currentItem;
 NSMutableString * _currentItemValue;
 NSMutableArray * _rssItems;
 id<BlogRssParserDelegate> _delegate;
 NSOperationQueue *_retrieverQueue;
 RootViewController *rootView;
 NSString *terms;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`terms` was prematurely released, most likely because you didn't retain it properly in the first place.  Coincidentally, an instance of `UITableViewCellLayoutManagerSubtitle` was subsequently allocated at said address that `terms` points to leading to the unrecognized method exception.

Use Zombie detection in Instruments to find the problem.

Also, use "Build and Analyze" as it is quite likely the llvm static analyzer will identify the issue.

Comment: Cool. I've gone under "Run" "Performance Tools" and "Zombies" is greyed out? Any ideas?

Comment: Try building first.   Since this is targeted to the iPhone, try reproducing it on the simulator.  Probably be easier to debug anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `terms` is being released prematurely and `UITableViewCellLayoutManagerSubtitle` is being alloced at the same memory address. Check your retain/release/autorelease commands are correct.